# How can I make the code inside a WHILE LOOP in SQL execute only once per LOOP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Question, how can I make the insert execute only 9 time? I say 9 because that's the value of @CN_COUNT. Instead this is executing 9*9. Any help will be really appreciate it.

```
DECLARE @CN_COUNT INT
, @DATE VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),101)
, @TIME VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),114)


SELECT @CN_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM CARTON_HEADER

DECLARE @CN INT
SET @CN = 1
WHILE (@CN  <= @CN_COUNT)
BEGIN
SET @CN = @CN + 1

INSERT INTO TM_CARTON(
    CN_NUMBER, CN_PICKTICKET, CN_LOAD_NUMBER, CN_SHIPMENT_NUMBER,         CN_PACKED_QTY, CN_TRACKING_NUMBER, 
    CN_ROUTE, CN_BOL, CN_MBOL, CN_PARCEL_NUMBER, CN_TRAILER_NUMBER, CN_CREATED_DATE, CN_CREATED_TIME)
SELECT 
    CN_NUMBER, CN_PICKTICKET, CN_LOAD_NUMBER, CN_SHIPMENT_NUMBER, CN_PACKED_QTY, CN_TRACKING_NUMBER, 
    CN_ROUTE, CN_BOL, CN_MBOL, CN_PARCEL_NUMBER, CN_TRAILER_NUMBER, @DATE, @TIME 
    FROM CARTON_HEADER WHERE CN_LOAD_NUMBER = '1000000002'

END
GO
```

Here is the example data:

```
  CN_NUMBER      CN_STATUS  CN_LOAD_NUMBER
  1001333311111 85  1000000002
  1001333311112 85  1000000002
  1001333311114 85  1000000002
  1001333311113 85  1000000002
  1001333311115 85  1000000002
  1001333311116 85  1000000002
  1001333311117 85  1000000002
  1001333311118 85  1000000002
  1001333311119 85  1000000002
```

The above data is on table A, I would like to get this copied to table B where CN_LOAD_NUMBER is something I declare in the statement

Sorry guys, I made this more complicated than what it was the solution is just a simple INSERT statement with NO loop.

```
INSERT INTO TM_CARTON(
CN_NUMBER, CN_PICKTICKET, CN_LOAD_NUMBER, CN_SHIPMENT_NUMBER,         CN_PACKED_QTY, CN_TRACKING_NUMBER, 
CN_ROUTE, CN_BOL, CN_MBOL, CN_PARCEL_NUMBER, CN_TRAILER_NUMBER, CN_CREATED_DATE, CN_CREATED_TIME)
SELECT 
CN_NUMBER, CN_PICKTICKET, CN_LOAD_NUMBER, CN_SHIPMENT_NUMBER, CN_PACKED_QTY, CN_TRACKING_NUMBER, 
CN_ROUTE, CN_BOL, CN_MBOL, CN_PARCEL_NUMBER, CN_TRAILER_NUMBER, @DATE, @TIME 
FROM CARTON_HEADER WHERE CN_LOAD_NUMBER = '1000000002'
```

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted will only execute 9 times.
If you are getting more inserts than you think you should be, it is because that select statement is returning more than one row.

After the first loop, you will have duplicated the row.  Thus, every successive iteration of the loop will return n+n rows, where n is the number of rows the previous iteration returned.

What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm doing a count on the CARTON_HEADER table, based on the count that's the number of inserts I want to per record in the CARTON_HEADER

Comment: So you want to get that count, \@CN_COUNT, and then find a row in one table and create \@CN_COUNT copies of that row in the TM_CARTON table?

Comment: Kind of, but those rows would different data

Comment: Not with the code above.  That will generate a bunch of identical rows, excluding any identity column.

Comment: So let say that on a table I have 9 records this is where the \@CN_COUNT is coming from. While my \@CN <= \@CN_COUNT I want to create a copy of each record into a different table. I might be approaching this the wrong way though

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and an example of how you expect it to end up?  I have an idea of what you might mean, but it's pretty fuzzy without some details.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example on how can I accomplish this??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the sample data is not formatting properly

Comment: Never mind, I figure it out. I was taking the wrong approach, long hours of work here. The solution is a simple INSERT statement with NO loop :-)

Comment: There ya go.  Sometimes writing it out and discussing it is enough to kick-start the old noodle. :)